# Comparing LAB Color histogram of superpixels OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, color-space

I am trying to compare the LAB color histogram of superpixels of couple of images with different metrics such as correlation, intersection and chi-squared. The problem is when I get the comparison result for each set of superpixels, they are all 0 or 1.

I guess the problem is with the range of values that I am using for each channel of LAB color space. This is the code (in OpenCV Python) that I use to get the color histogram for each superpixel:

```
segment = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask = mask), cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)

hist = cv2.calcHist([segment], [0, 1, 2], None, [8, 8, 8],[0, 100, -110, 110, -110, 110])
cv2.normalize(hist, hist)
hist = hist.flatten()
```

Then, I save these histograms and compare them together. When I do it for RGB, I get normal results, but this is not the case for LAB. I would appreciate if someone could give me a hint on what I might be doing wrong here.

Comment: Are you sure that the ranges of your Lab image are right? It seems to me that OpenCV stores values between 0 and 255 for all channels if you are working on 8 bit precision images.

Comment: But doesn't it depend on the range of each channel?

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor.  Go down to where the conversion between rgb and lab is defined. You will see that OpenCV applies special transformations for 8 bit images to change the range to [0-255]

Comment: So just to make sure, this means, as you said before, the values of each channel of LAB is between 0 and 255, right? Thanks again for your help!